# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html Rails errors: NoMethodError in Articles#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and seeing this error when submitting the form at localhost:3000/articles/new

```
NoMethodError in Articles#show
```

I am following along the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html tutorial step for step.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
      @articles = Article.all
    end
end
```

Here is the link to the Github repository for my code.  I'm using Rails version 4.1.7.  Any help will be appreciated!

https://github.com/z20/rails_start

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While a brief version of the error and a link to the Github repo is good, it is better to provide a verbose version of the error message and a snippet of the error-triggering code. Code formatting for that information is also good practice -- it's easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
      @articles = Article.all
    end
end
```

should be changed to:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end     

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

`show` is private in your code, and should be public. Move the private after your actions. When you set `private` in a class, everything that comes after that `private` will be inaccessible outside of that specific class.